# Google Sheet: How to compare two columns and find the exact or partial match?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have to compare two columns and highlight the text when it's exact or partial match in google sheet.

My data:

| Working Data (A Column) | Matching List data( B Column) |
| --- | --- |
| Jhon | Jhon Doe |
| Cycle Industries LTD | Cycle Industries |
| Cycle Industries | Manufacture Company |
| Cycle Industries | Engineering Company |
| Food |  |
| Engineering Company |  |

I will give entry to the column A, and it will match the column B data and marked the match one.

I have tried this custom formula in conditional formating:

```
=COUNTIFS(B:B,A1)>0
```

But its only marked the exact match data. How can I find the maximum partially match data and exact match data also?

Comment: Try `=COUNTIFS(B:B,"*" & A1 & "*")>0`

Comment: The solution proposed by @Harun24hr solves the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the double match you can use:

```
=OR(ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(--REGEXMATCH($B$2:$B,A2))),--REGEXMATCH(A2,TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,$B$2:$B)))
```

The first match if A is in B, 2nd match if B is in A, you can use one of these or combined as I wrote, this marks every entry in A except *food*

bye.

Comment: I need only match Column A with B. No need double match.

Comment: You see the results in [Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AzFnHNq2-ZErVDo1XYYd77N21yxk8uTjjZRJNB_ffkc/edit?usp=sharing)
Two different results in _sngM_ or _dblM_